# Systemd service unit not starting at boot unless #[Unit] is commented out

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, services

Running up to date Arch Linux ARMv7 (RaspPi 3). I have two systemd service units which I have created. I want `foo` to start first and then `bar`. `foo` starts on boot and `bar` does not. However `bar` will start manually from a shell prompt. Here is a copy of the `bar` unit file:

```
[Unit]
Requires=foo.service
After=foo.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setsid /usr/bin/bar >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null
TimeoutSec=0
RemainAfterExit=Yes

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target
```

However if I put a pound symbol in front of `[Unit]` like so:

```
#[Unit]
```

Then `bar` starts at boot in the right order (after `foo`).

This behaviour and commenting out of the `[Unit]` line doesn't seem to make sense or fit in with the documentation I can find. So I'm just wondering why it makes the unit start at boot?!

Comment: Someone has downvoted the question... please comment to tell me what I did wrong? I have spend a lot of time going through documentation to find an answer and can't.

Comment: Are the four lines above **all** of the service file?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae No, sorry - added the whole file now

Comment: It's circular: you are trying to start */usr/bin/bar* but the service file says it requires *bar*, and must be started after *bar*.

Comment: sorry @MariusMatutiae my mistake! edited again... it's because foo and bar are not the real service names. I renamed them for the question and confused myself!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting out `[Unit]` causes the `Requires` and `After` directives to be ignored. Removing those directives and removing the comment `#` gives identical behaviour.

The reason it was not starting at boot without the comment `#` must be because of an issue with the requirement for the other service.